# Printing only specific keys in a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, key

I've been trying to make my small application print only specific keys within a hashmap (of which do not contain 'unwanted' strings). The way in which I attempted this is shown below:

```
Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String[] unwanted = {"hi", "oat"};

    items.put("black shoes", 1);
    items.put("light coat", 10);
    items.put("white shoes", 40);
    items.put("dark coat", 90);

    for(int i = 0; i < unwanted.length; i++) {
        for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            if(!entry.getKey().contains(unwanted[i])) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Yet it prints this:

```
dark coat = 90
black shoes = 1
light coat = 10
white shoes = 40
black shoes = 1
```

However, it is meant to print this instead (as it's supposed to omit the keys with "hi" and "oat" within them which should just leave:)

```
black shoes = 1
```

I don't know why I am failing to see the fault but hopefully someone can help me point it out.

Comment: you have to check if any of your unwanted strings can be found in every key before printing them out... in your solution yoor for loop only checks if one of your two unwanted strings are in the key.
E.g. if (!black shores.contains("hi")) sysout(...)
that's why you have your wrong outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop logic is not correct. It will print a hashmap entry as long as one the unwanted string is not present.

change the for loop logic to as shown below...

```
bool found = false;
for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
    found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < unwanted.length; i++) {
        if(entry.getKey().contains(unwanted[i])) {
           found = true;            
        }
    }
    if(found == false)
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see your outer loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < unwanted.length; i++)
```

then it iterates thru

```
String[] unwanted = {"hi", "oat"};
```

Your map is as:

```
"dark coat" : 90
"white shoes": 40
"light coat" : 10
"black shoes", 1
```

Hence in first iteration,

```
unwanted[i]="hi"
```

So your inner loop does not print "white shoes" and rather it prints:

```
dark coat = 90
black shoes = 1
light coat = 10
```

as they do not contain "hi"

In the second interation,

```
unwanted[i]="oat"
```

So your inner loop does not print `"dark coat"` and `"light coat"` and prints the remaining from the map:

```
white shoes = 40
black shoes = 1
```

Thus you are getting the combined output of above two iterations as:

```
dark coat = 90
black shoes = 1
light coat = 10
white shoes = 40
black shoes = 1
```

So what you can do is try this code in which the inner loop and outer loops are flipped:

```
Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String[] unwanted = {"hi", "oat"};
    items.put("black shoes", 1);
    items.put("light coat", 10);
    items.put("white shoes", 40);
    items.put("dark coat", 90);

    boolean flag;
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
        if(!stringContainsItemFromList(entry.getKey(),unwanted))
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

In above code, we have used static function:

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputString, String[] items)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputString.contains(items[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope that helped!!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to first get all entries of your `map` through `entrySet`, `iterate` through the list of entries, in `ith` iteration fetch `ith` entry and then print it's value

```
Iterator itr = yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
    System.out.print("(Key: " + entry.getKey() + " ,  Value:" + entry.getValue()); 
}
```